# Siblings of multiple list items

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, I have come to the conclusion that .siblings() by default only allows one selector or element to be the parent, and only the rest can be siblings.

How would one say to apply a class to multiple items and remove the class from the rest of the siblings?

```
$("#CarePointSAHAIDID").click(function() {  
    $("li.carepoint, li.saha, li.idid").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");      
  });
```

Sorry, I thought I posted the HTML

```
    <ul>
<li class="hometownnorth"><a href="#"></a></li>
<li class="clearwater"><a href="#"></a></li>
<li class="kootenai"><a href="#"></a></li>
<li class="carepoint"><a href="#"></a></li>
<li class="saha"><a href="#"></a></li>
<li class="idid"><a href="#"></a></li>
<li class="hometowneast"><a href="#"></a></li>
<li class="portneuf"><a href="#"></a></li>
<li class="mountainview"><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: We need to see your HTML here, but assuming `.carepoint`, `.saha` and `.idid` are all siblings of each other, then you're removing the class from all but the last one to execute in the loop through the elements in the jQuery object.

Comment: You say "two items" but your code shows a selector that could return more than two. Not entirely sure what you're asking.

Comment: Why not just remove the class from all the list items first, then add the class to those that need it? `.siblings()` might actually work, but without seeing your HTML we can't tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just remove the collection by adding `.not()`:

```
$("li.carepoint, li.saha, li.idid").addClass("active").siblings().not("li.carepoint, li.saha, li.idid").removeClass("active");
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ncLu3zz9/)**

The docs for [.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) actually says:

> If you need an exclusive
>   list of siblings, use `$collection.siblings().not($collection)`.

A simple alternative is to remove the active class from all the list items first and then just add them to the ones you want:

```
$("li").removeClass("active");
$("li.carepoint, li.saha, li.idid").addClass("active");
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/77g4fw6w/)**

Comment: This worked. Thank you.

Comment: Not worthy of being a separate solution, but I threw together this one - it's a bit of a hybrid of the two approaches but closer to the second. Avoids querying the whole Document twice like the first solution, but the approach is more like the second - remove active from all and add to those that need it. The use of siblings in this case is completely extraneous, it expands the scope just to filter it again. https://jsfiddle.net/svcc9vje/

Answer (score 0):

you can always remove all class `active` and then add `active` to the ones you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".clickme").on('click', function() {
    $("li").removeClass("active");
    $("li.carepoint, li.saha, li.idid").addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="hometownnorth"><a href="#">hometownnorth</a></li>
<li class="clearwater"><a href="#">clearwater</a></li>
<li class="kootenai"><a href="#">kootenai</a></li>
<li class="carepoint"><a href="#">carepoint</a></li>
<li class="saha"><a href="#">saha</a></li>
<li class="idid"><a href="#">idid</a></li>
<li class="hometowneast"><a href="#">hometowneast</a></li>
<li class="portneuf"><a href="#">portneuf</a></li>
<li class="mountainview"><a href="#">mountainview</a></li>
</ul>

<button class="clickme">clickme</button>
```